# How to detect if there is text in textarea tag under a rect shape div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my situation as you see in the picture. I am working on a markdown editor. A floating command button panel is visible, when mouse over the textarea. The command button panel is absolute positioned at the top right corner of the textarea.

But some times, text in textarea is blocked by the command panel, making selecting the text underneath it impossible.

I'd like to detect a situation when there is a text under the command panel, then apply a class to shift command panel up 50px.

Here is my question: How to detect if there is text in textarea tag under a rect shape div?

Thanks!

AS you can see in the below picture, the command panel hovering over textarea blocks the text. I'd like to detect this situation.

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, other than the first line wouldn't the command panel always be covering text?

Comment: The first line is text in textarea, because I didn't want the command panel to occupy a horizontal area when not needed. When visible, the command panel is inside the textarea, and the panel is only visible when mouse over the textarea.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand what you mean (perhaps others will though). Maybe you could upload so more images of what you want to happen in different scenarios?

Comment: If you make the textarea **unresizable** then just type a bunch of text until it hits the next line and check the length. Then make a mouseover function on the command panel that checks the length and if it's greater than the line hide it or move it

Comment: what does the HTML of the textarea look like?

Answer (score 0):

So, one thing that you can do is get the width of the text area. AKA the `cols` attribute of the `textarea`.

Once you have the width of the text area, you get the text (`textarea` value) within the text area and find the length of that text. If the length of the text within the `textarea` is greater than the number of `cols` you know that the text will span the length of the `textarea`.

One very apparent caveat is that lets say you are writing a poem or something and the text never spans the length of a full line, that length will be longer than the number of `cols` while never actually spanning the full length of the `textarea`

Another inherent issue is that if you start scrolling in your `textarea` new text may come underneath the controls.

I don't really think it would be possible to detect whether or not text inside of a `textarea` is underneath a certain `div`.

What I would probably suggest doing is just always have the controls `div` `50px` higher than the `textarea`. Simple solution, that will still look good and won't require any crazy coding on your part, because I can't really picture an easy way (or any way for that matter) to do this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I've had to do something similar for a resizing textarea in the past. The secret is to have  an offscreen input or textarea with variable width. As the text is updated in your visible text field, copy the text over to the off screen element element. The shadow element has to have *all* of the same styling that affects the visible element (padding, border, width, height, font size, etc) to make sure you get accurate results. Then measure the width of the shadow element on each text change.